# Nice way to use com.sun.tools.attach package in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I would like to use the classes of com.sun.tools.attach package within an Eclipse Plugin.

I would not like to use *Bundle-ClassPath: external:$java.home$/../lib/tools.jar* if possible, as tools.jar will be replaced by several JMOD files in Java 9.

I would not like to specify the system.packages system property as in that case I should always make the users modifying their Eclipse installation, too.

Does anybody know a nice way to access the classes of tools.jar within an Eclipse Plugin?

Comment: I guess you indicated the known solutions already ;-). If you can't or don't want those, you probably need to re-package the classes into your bundle.

Comment: I will stick with the "Bundle-ClassPath: external:..." version for now, but I hope there will be a JDK version independent answer to this question before JDK9 comes out. I was also thinking of re-packaging, but I do not know if there is any licensing issues with that. Also, I am not that familiar with the native code support of OSGi.